# command "find ... -exec mv ..." created a file with strange content

Tags: shell, files, mv

I wanted to move binary files from folder `/myhome/sourcedir` to `/myhome/targetdir`.
I used a command `find /myhome/sourcedir -type f -cmin +3 -exec mv '{}' /myhome/targetdir ';'`

Folder `/myhome/sourcedir` existed before this command executed, but folder `/myhome/targetdir` did not exist. I just forgot to create `/myhome/targetdir`.

Result of this command - new file `/myhome/targetdir` was created. File is very big and contain lots of strange symbols ))

How to restore all my files?

Comment: Tip: when you know that something is a directory, type `/myhome/targetdir/`. The trailing `/` forces the file to be a directory. Then `mv` would have complained `mv: accessing ‘/myhome/targetdir/’: Not a directory`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume the `find` found 3 files: a, b, and c. This resulted in 3 commands:

```
mv a /myhome/targetdir
mv b /myhome/targetdir
mv c /myhome/targetdir
```

so, a was renamed to /myhome/targetdir, then b was renamed to /myhome/targetdir (destroying what used to be a), and then c was renamed to /myhome/targetdir, destroying what used to be b. file c is fine (it has just been renamed). The other files are in trouble. Have a look at [Can overwritten files be recovered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered). You  might be able to recover something.

In the future, using:

```
mv -t /myhome/targetdir '{}'
```

Would be safer.

Comment: This is one of my pet peeves against Unix: that cp and mv with two arguments do conceptually quite different things depending on whether the second argument is an existing directory or not.

Comment: @Bjorn, it can lead to some disastrous results, but it does seem like a pretty natural syntax to me. What would the alternative be? Seperate mv and rename commands?

Comment: My pet peeve is that there is probably tons of free space on the hard drive; it should be trivial to recover any file until the space needs to be reclaimed (unless I `shred` it).