# Restore deleted text file content

Tags: restore, deleted-files

I just wrote an important text and stored it as a simple text file. Then i accidentally cut out the content (with Ctrl+X) when i just wanted to copy it, and saved the file. Now it is of course empty. Is there any possibility to get the content back?
Any help is very much appreciated, it really took some time to write it.

Comment: Without knowing how you "cut" the text there's little chance to offer a solution. Please [edit] your question to provide the missing information. (Remember that we didn't see you do it, and we don't know anything about your computing environment.)

Comment: I was able to restore it but thank you for your comment :)

Comment: I tried to but there's a message that says i can't do it before tomorrow. Will do it then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it with help of the accepted answer here: [Can overwritten files be recovered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered)

> For larger files that may be in multiple non-contiguous blocks, I do this:
>
> grep -a -b "text in the deleted file" /dev/sda1
>   13813610612:this is some text in the deleted file
>   which will give you the offset in bytes of the matching line. Follow this with a series of dd commands, starting with
>
> dd if=/dev/sda1 count=1 skip=$(expr 13813610612 / 512)
>   You'd also want to read some blocks before and after that block.

I needed to set count to 10 to get my entire file, has to be chosen by file size.