# ERROR: unexpected end of the file

Tags: files, mv

I have to unpack a `tar.gz` file after moving it to a folder. While moving it to destination folder, I unexpectedly tried to move it to `]` named folder and gave <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> . Now half of the files are in `tar.gz` and half in `]`.

Then I tried to move `]`  into `tar.gz` and it was moved.

Now when I try  to unpack the file it is showing `unexpected end of file` error.

Is there any way to bring back the `]` from `tar.gz` and make the exact `tar.gz` file and unzip the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not how `mv` works.

I'm assuming that you are talking about a single file that you accidentally moved to the wrong name on another filesystem (and interrupted the transfer half-way through), and then moved the wrongly named file back to its original location and name.

If the file moves within the same filesystem, the move is *pretty much* instantaneous (it's just a renaming of the file and does not even touch the file's content).

If the file is moved to a new filesystem, then the file contents is copied, *then* the original is deleted.

If you moved the file between filesystems and interrupted the process, the original would still have been intact. But since you now have overwritten the original with the partial copy, the original is unfortunately lost.

Restore from backup, if you have one.

See also: [Can overwritten files be recovered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered)