# Restore empty docker-compose file

Tags: docker, nano

I was working on a sizeable docker-compose file using the nano editor. Upon saving it told me I was out of disk space. Without hesitating, I quit nano, extended my LVM and resized the FS as I have done countless times before only to discover that apparently nano had accidentally removed the content of my docker-compose file and left me with an empty file.

The containers I described in the docker-compose file are currently still running. Is there any chance of recovering the file (or at least the docker container configs)?

By the way, don't ask me if I can restore from a backup... If I could, I wouldn't be asking for help ;-)

Comment: Is there a file with the same name and a `~` suffix?

Comment: No sadly not - however, I think I was able to recover it by following the idea outlined here to use grep to search the entire disk for a known string: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered