# Tar archive overwrote original file

Tags: ubuntu, tar, data-recovery, restore, xz

I was compressing a rosbag file using tar when I mistakenly used the same original file name for the the archive name and had it overwritten by the output archive , the compressed archive size is very small compared to the expected output had I used another name e.g., file.tar.xz.
When I extract the archive , I get a file of type "STL 3D model (binary) (model/x.stl-binary)" instead of the original bag file of type "Binary (application/octet-stream)". The file size is the same but the format is different.

Is there a way to retrieve the original file or is this irreversible ? kindly find below the commands used to compress then extract the file.

```
tar -cJf <file.bag> <file.bag>
tar -xf <file.bag>
```

any help would be much appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly, the file is probably gone, depending on your system, but if it is a default Ubuntu install it won't have snapshots turned on. secondly, you may find that the file type is different, depending on the source of the object. `application/octet-stream` is often used as a generic object type, or used by lazy systems to identify binary objects.  it could be that your object always was a `model/x.stl-binary`

Comment: Depending on how the file was stored on the drive, you could try some file recovery software; i.e, If there were multiple instances of the data that was in the file written to the disk.  *Testdisk* is a free one that works well.

Comment: See this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered