# Recover content of text file that has been replaced with another text file which has the same name

Tags: ext4, data-recovery

I have saved a text file using Gedit text editor in my /home/Desktop directory. Unfortunately there was already a text file with the same name there, so its content has been lost. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and ext4 filesystem.

This question explains how to recover its content if you remember some text of the file that has been replaced:
[Can overwritten files be recovered?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/can-overwritten-files-be-recovered)

It uses this command:
`grep -i -a -B100 -A100 'text in the deleted file' /dev/sda1 > recovered-text.txt`

The problem is that I can not remember some of the text of the lost file. It was an old file which I had not opened in a long time.

Is there a way to retrieve it if I only know the name of that text file? Is there a chance that the filename is saved as metadata in disk next to the file content which I could grep? Any suggestions?